# How to set up stripe on web page

Tags: php

I uploaded the code Stripe instructed in **Step 1: Embed the Checkout** on my PHP webpage:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_ghkfasasgipnDFA6fAB"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

**Then I uploaded the PHP code on the same web page below the code mentioned above:**

```
// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in               production
// See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_ghkfasasgipnDFA6fAB");

    // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

// Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
try {
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
  "currency" => "usd",
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "payinguser@example.com")
);
} catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
  // The card has been declined
}
```

**After bringing the web page onto my FTP server the first code worked but the second did not. If anyone may know why any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.**

Comment: What was the error? Just nothing happened, or was there a message?

Comment: The second code just read on the web page as words.

Comment: Is your code inside of php tags?

Comment: The way the code is above is how its on my site.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the second code in `<?php`  `?>` tags so your page would be.

somepage.php

```
 <form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_ghkfasasgipnDFA6fAB"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>

<?php
    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in               production
    // See your keys here https://dashboard.stripe.com/account
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_ghkfasasgipnDFA6fAB");

        // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

    // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card
    try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      "amount" => 1000, // amount in cents, again
      "currency" => "usd",
      "source" => $token,
      "description" => "payinguser@example.com")
    );
    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
      // The card has been declined
    }
 ?>
```

The thing is, the line `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("...")` is referring to a PHP Class, that is not in the script above.  This means there is some other code some where, that should be included in the page as well. Do you have the stripe php library installed as well?  https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/php

Comment: It looks like in Dreamweaver the code was recognized. The web page didnt come up this time though, just a "Warning: Unexpected character in input:" I haven't installed a stripe php library. Is there more you have to do then just copy and paste the code?

Comment: Yes according to the guide that I linked to just above. (1.) You have to be using PHP 5.3.3,8 (2.) have to have the "Stripe PHP Library," installed using Composer (3.) Have to create a "config.php" file (4.) Then explains how to make a "charge.php" file as well.